# performance testing in sql server management studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

how to Insert sample data for table use in performance testing in sql server management studio

Comment: Can you be more clear and specific?

Comment: when we inserting a data into sql server tables, we can test the performance while executing queries. my question is what are the techniques available for that task?

Comment: Take a look at [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To populate large tables you can use the following approach where you can set the number wish rows:

```
CREATE Table Persons
(
   Id int identity primary key,
   Name nvarchar(50),
   Country nvarchar(50)
)



Declare @Id int
set nocount on; 
declare @start datetime = getutcdate();  

declare @i int = 0;
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 120000
   Begin 
   Insert Into Persons values ('Name - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),
          'Country - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name')
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
END

SELECT datediff(ms, @start, getutcdate());
```

In addition, it is possible to use `SET STATISTICS TIME ON`

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SET STATISTICS IO ON 
GO
Declare @Id int
set nocount on;     

declare @i int = 0;
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 120000
   Begin 
   Insert Into Persons values ('Name - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),
          'Country - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name')
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
END
SET STATISTICS IO OFF 
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
GO
```

Comment: Hey StepUp thanks for the Answer.i have one question where is the Performance testing?

Comment: @KMS ooops, I forgot to add measurements. Please, see my updated answer

Comment: @KMS I am glad to help you! :)

Comment: i run your code. but it has following error - Must declare the scalar variable "@start".

Comment: @KMS I've tested in SSMS. May be you highlighted piece of code without declaration. Just click `CTRL+ A`, then `Execute(F5)` in SSMS.

Comment: i have some problem....when i doing this performance testing for a Foreign key referenced table, how could i change this code???

Comment: @KMS Is this field `NULLable`?  If yes, then just insert `null` value, if no, then insert some hardcoded value from referenced coulmn.

Answer (score 0):

There are many techniques you can go with, out of which few are listed below.

1. Add `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` above your inserting query.
2. Include `Execution Plan` and execute existing and optimized both the queries in same Query tab(By pressing Ctrl+N) and see into execution plan which query have taken more percentage to get executed.
3. You can have both existing and optimized queries into same Query tab(By pressing Ctrl+N) and Add `PRINT GETDATE()` after both the insert queries and take out the difference of both the times.

There may be many other techniques, these are few which I use normally.

Comment: Thank you very much Man